# Nodejs request module: how to add paremeters in body when using method get

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I am using nodejs request module to send a get request, the parameters are put in a body, code is as below:

```
request({
    url: url,
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        'Content-Type':'application/json'
    },
    body: {
        'sort_field':'age',
        'page_size':10,
        'page':1   
    }
}, function(err, resp, body){
       if(!err && resp.statusCode == 200) {
           res.send(body);
       }     
})
```

However, I couldn't get anything, the nodejs server side has an error message:

**TypeError: first argument must be a string or Buffer**

Is there anything wrong when using request module to send a get request with body parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the parameters after the url: url?sort_field=age&page_size=10&page=1

Comment: The api doc said the parameters are put in body, I feel also wired. I tried the paramters but with nothing

Comment: use data instead of body:data: {
        'sort_field':'age',
        'page_size':10,
        'page':1   
    }

Comment: get parameter:req.param('sort_field')

Answer (score 0):

From the request doc you could see:

> `body` - entity body for PATCH, POST and PUT requests. Must be a `Buffer`, `String` or `ReadStream`. If `json` is true, then body must be a JSON-serializable object.

so fix your code:

```
request({
    url: url,
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        'Content-Type':'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        'sort_field':'age',
        'page_size':10,
        'page':1   
    })
}, function(err, resp, body){
    if(!err && resp.statusCode == 200) {
        res.send(body);
    }     
})
```

I've not tested this solution, please tell me if it works :)